# Fastest way to take columns from individual Fixed-width files and place in new CSV file using Dask

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dask

#### Problem

I have a variable number of fixed-width files that contain time-series data for a large number of channels. I need to extract user specified columns and save them to a new csv file.

#### Data Format of fixed-width Files

- No header (column name information/order/index is stored in a separate file)
- From 2-11 columns
- First column always contains time
- Typically the number of rows is in the order of tens of thousands
- Fixed column width format
- All data is real numbers
- All files are exactly the same length

#### Example Data

```
    0.0000000000000         0.0000000000000         0.0000000000000         0.0000000000000         0.0000000000000         0.0000000000000         0.0000000000000         0.0000000000000         0.0000000000000         0.0000000000000         0.0000000000000    
   0.20000000000000E-02   -0.78316746164705E-05   -0.55588946130087E-02    0.23977249743147E-02     1.0000000000000       -0.55055077745381E-07     0.0000000000000       -0.33601773744944E-10    0.24453720011883E-01     1.0000000000000       -0.48147397355603E-02
   0.40000000000000E-02   -0.63538465850783E-02   -0.93035113950468E-01    0.35370312419918E-01     1.0000000000000       -0.99610928097310E-02     0.0000000000000        0.39549619607471E-03    0.26770274111205         1.0000000000000       -0.26102761850179E-01
   0.60000000000000E-02   -0.33649747866341E-01   -0.12820456839496        0.15502082128837         1.0000000000000       -0.45260056706573E-01     0.0000000000000        0.23408807718764E-01     1.0563887132504         1.0000000000000       -0.72621886780765E-01
```

#### Example Operation

File 1:

```
Time A B C D
```

File 2:

```
Time E F G
```

File 3:

```
Time H I J K L M
```

Output:

```
Time A B J K L
```

#### What I have Tried

I have tried reading using Pandas, numpy, and the standard python csv dict but it was too slow for my application. With Dask I tried individually loading the files into Dask.dataframes, creating a copy of the time column, dropping all time columns from each dataframe, then concatenating frames and indexing the user requested columns.

#### Goal

I would like to be able to complete this operation with 100 channels from 25 files (25000 rows each) in under a second. If there is a better way that I have not considered please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if under a second is feasible, but what I would do is use `delayed` to parallelise the code that works (but is slow). It would look like this:

```py
import dask

@dask.delayed
def my_func(filename):
    # your custom code that works, but is slow
    return df

# this is a list of dataframes
[computed_dfs] = dask.compute([my_func(f) for f in list_files])

# concatenate dfs
df_final = pd.concat(computed_dfs)
```

Note that in your question you mention that you only want to return some columns, I would implement this column drop/subset logic inside `my_func` to reduce the amount of data transfer from workers to client.